# What is this entertainment symbol?

Tags: tropico-6

This shows up when I go to add more entertainment to my island. I think I missed it in the tutorial, does it mean citizens already have nearby entertainment?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/tropico/comments/bvmhyj/tropico_6_what_does_the_icon_above_the_tavern_mean/),

> **it means [the building is] at capacity**, and people have to wait in line to use that building.

Which practically means you have to

> build another one.